# How does div function in assembly language using fixed point arithmetic?

Tags: assembly, x86, division, fixed-point

Hi I am new to assembly language and I am trying to understand how to use fixed point numbers in a division in x86 assembly language. When I use `div` (using registers `ax`, `bx` and `dx`) the result is not exact and I don't know why.

Thank you for your help!

Update #1 (1000 and 900 are already fixed point numbers)

```
mov ax, 1000
mov bx, 900
shl dx, 8
div bx
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you wanted to compute and what code you tried to do it with?

Comment: I am trying to divide two 8.8 format fixed point numbers in registers with 16bit.

Comment: How did you do it? There should be a "pre-shift" 8 to the left (shifting into `dx`) to compensate for the division "losing" 8 bits, that's a detail that I can see going wrong

Comment: What do you mean by a "pre shift"? I put a number in bx and ax and then call `div bx`

Comment: Shifting left before the "div" operation. By contrast multiplication needs a "post-shift" (shifting right after the multiplication). At least that is the case generically, there are special cases where the shift can be (or should be) skipped, such as chaining a multiply into a divide.

Comment: If I do it I get a `program crashed` error

Comment: Show the code, we can try to guess what code you wrote but that is not accurate

Comment: Update#1 is a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pre-shift" before a division, if the dividend was in `ax`, should shift and widen `ax` into `dx:ax`. In a diagram, it could look like this:

```
Take this, in ax:

+------+------+
| high | low  |
+------+------+

Turn it into this, in dx:ax  

+------+------+ +------+------+
|  0   | high |:| low  |   0  |
+------+------+ +------+------+
```

`shl dx, 8` is not enough, that affects only `dx` but not `ax`. You could do it like this:

```
mov dx, ax
shr dx, 8
shl ax, 8
div bx
```

Or you could do something with the 8-bit registers that make up `dx` and `ax`, but I do not recommend that.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But if you wouldn't mind could you explain me why I need to do the shifts in order to do the division? Because I am having trouble imaging the numbers in the registers with the shifting

Comment: @some_programmer another way to think about this (not at the bit-level) is that fixed-point numbers have an implicit scale (instead of having the original number `x` we have `256 * x` in a register), and division divides both the numbers and their scales. If the scales of the inputs are the same, then the result has a scale of 1, so it's a plain integer. In order to make the result come out with the intended scale, the dividend is first multiplied by the scale again. The division gets rid of that extra scale, leaving us with only the intended scale.

Comment: The code ends up slightly more complicated than "multiply by the scale" because the value ends up being "split" over two registers. For example if we had 32bit code here, but still 8.8 fixed point, we could just use `shl eax, 8` to implement this multiplication by the scale (and set `edx` to zero).